# Laravel not executing queries with 'having' clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent, having

I have manually built a large query using the various eloquent functions (i.e. $this->newQuery()->join....), but I can't get it to run.

When I call

```
echo $query->toSql();
```

It shows me the query. I can copy and paste it into my command line mysql client, and it runs fine, and returns several rows. But when I call

```
echo $query->count();
```

or

```
echo $query->get()->count();
```

It's showing 0.

I eventually enabled my mysql general log to see what was happening. I see that as laravel runs, it executes several queries - each has a `prepare` line in the log, followed by an `execute` line. But this one doesn't.

It appears that laravel is preparing the statement, but never executing it. Why not?

After much testing, I have identified the line that causes the problem:

```
$query->having('book_author_author_id', 'NOT IN', DB::raw('('.implode(',',$author_ids).')'));
```

It appears that queries which contain a 'having' clause are not executed by laravel, instead it pretends to execute them and returns an empty collection. What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

The problems turns out to be that laravel is not correctly resolving DB::raw statements in a having clause. Since it also does not allow arrays to be passed through, this has the practical effect of making it impossible to write a query with `having x in (1,2,3)`. Instead, the solution is to do several separate having clauses. So in this case, like this:

```
foreach($author_ids as $id) {
    $query->having('book_author_author_id', '!=', $id);
}
```

Yet another irritating example of Eloquent's restricted functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query->havingRaw(
  "{book_author_author_id} IN ('". implode("','", $author_ids) . "')"
);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question improves its long-term value.